# Auto-complete functionality for Solr Sunspot

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, solr, autocomplete, sunspot

I did a RoR project with a search tab and auto-complete functionality. I used a MySQL database to store the data and used jQuery ui for auto-complete. Now I'm doing the same project with a Solr Sunspot. I've my search functionality working. Can I use the same jQuery ui to implement the auto-complete feature by using the same strategy I used for MySQL. Will the jQuery auto-complete fetch the data in the same way for Sunspot as it did with MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.... auto-complete js snippet just captures search text from input field and send them to backend controller/action..... then ruby action fetches matching data.... it depends on how and from where you fetch data either from Solr or database..... and controller/action responds to auto-search js snippet with data you would provide...